# Trying to add isotope to a grid gallery but it hides every item instead

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

So i have a gallery of items, its basically a grid of divs. When i add isotope to it, just initializing it hides every single item. This is the basic layout that i have of a gallery.

```
 <div class="items">
            <div class="item react">
                <div class="item-image">
                    <img src="img/items/item1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-text">
                    <div class="item-text-wrap">
                        <p class="item-text-category">Design1</p>
                        <h2 class="item-text-title">Item Title 1</h2>
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fab fa-twitter" href="index.html"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div>
```

Now without adding isotope everything works fine. However, when i init it with

```
$(".items").isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item'

        });
```

The entire gallery section disappears, upon inspection. I see that isotope kind of works(yes i included jquery and scripts and checked if they loaded), but what it does is set the grid container position to relative with height of 0px, and every item in it a position of absolute, left 0, top 0. How can i go about fixing this?><

Comment: it seems that initializing isotope doesnt cause the problem , as you can see here: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/xxKLJpq?editors=1010 the problem seems to be with your css , or ... (perhaps your element is hidden when you init isotop, so isotop can't get it's height and it cause problem, or something similar)

Comment: You might be right, my divs have no gaps and my images in those divs are displayed as blocks with height auto, there is a bunch of other css stuff like sliding overlays and texts. Might probably just keep it as it is.